# PuLP objective function not incorporating constant in lpSum

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, pulp

***Any idea why the following objective function doesn't include the -5000 in its formulation?***

```
prob += lp.lpSum([-5000 + price_today_d[i] * ticker_vars[i] for i in ticker_list]), 'Total Cost'
```

**Result:**

```
Total_Cost: 0.82 ticker_A + 27.55 ticker_B
 + 32.73 ticker_C + 30.14 ticker_D + 26.55 ticker_E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default PuLP ignores constant values since they are not relevant for obtaining the optimal solution. You can always add it after solving.

Comment: darn, I just want it to be cleaner in the model file rather than edit it later.